# Segmentation fault in C++ printing all the subsequences with an equal sum

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(int ind,vector<int>&ar,int sum,int target,int nums[],int n)
{
    //cout<<sum<<" ";
    if(ind == n)
    {
        if(sum == target)
        {
            cout<<2<<endl;
            for(auto it:ar)
            {
                cout<<it<<" ";
            }
            return ;
        }
    }
    ar.push_back(nums[ind]);
    sum+=nums[ind];

    solve(ind+1,ar,sum,target,nums,n);

    sum-=nums[ind];
    ar.pop_back();

    solve(ind+1,ar,sum,target,nums,n);
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {1,2,1};
    int target = 2;
    int n = 3;
    vector<int>ar;
    int sum = 0;
    solve(0,ar,0,target,nums,n);
}
```

The code is giving a segmentation fault in an online compiler and in VSCode it is not showing any output. I don't know what's wrong in this code and have been trying to figure it out for a long time now.

Error traceback:

```
/bin/bash: line 1:    18 Segmentation fault      timeout 15s ./f9f11492-657e-4e6a-b05c-ffc40f6540ea < f9f11492-657e-4e6a-b05c-ffc40f6540ea.in
```

Comment: If `ind == n`, but `sum != target`, then you go out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? Can you even explain the first line? I ask because most people who use that line cannot give any reason which is applicable for the purpose of the shown program and they do not know how to replace it with code which does have reasons within the given scope.

Comment: Wherever you learned `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, block that site in your browser, forget everything you saw there, and never go there again.

Comment: I'm not quite as harsh, but I do see `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` as a warning that I should expose what I find on the site to a much higher level of scrutiny.

Answer (score 2):

Try shifting the `return` statement outside the `if` block. Like others have mentioned, the problem is, if `ind == n` but `sum` and `target` does not match, there is no `return` that happens and then `nums[ind]` will give out of bound error.

It should be

```
//cout<<sum<<" ";
        if(ind == n)
        {
           if(sum == target)
           {
               cout<<2<<endl;
               for(auto it:ar)
               {
                   cout<<it<<" ";
               }
           }
           return ;
        }
.... <remaining code follows>
```